# how can I add links to my nav bar in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to javascript.
I am trying to add a link (Section 1) to my nav bar and I am not sure why I still can't see it in the preview.

```
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.classList.add('menu__link');
link.href = '#section1';
link.textContent = 'Section 1';
document.getElementById('navbar__list').appendChild(link);
```

Comment: the second line should be link.classList instead of ink.classList.. what are you using to preview it?

Comment: My bad... in the process of copy-paste my code to here, I copied "ink" instead of "link"!
So in the actual file, it is correct.

Comment: I am using live server extension on my vscode.

Answer (score 1):

in the second line of your code 'l' letter of 'link' word is missing.

```js
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.classList.add('menu__link');
link.href = '#section1';
link.textContent = 'Section 1';
document.getElementById('navbar__list').appendChild(link);
```